# Question about request chains and waiting on data

Tags: javascript, node.js

In NodeJS, I have an application that needs to dynamically create request instances based on total followers a streamer has because, I can only pull 100 users per call. Twitch than provides me with a cursor to the next 100 and so on.

It is not possible to chain requests to get this info for streamers with 500k followers of course and can't seem to find a way to get this to work.

Any ideas?

```
const request = require('request')

var value = 0

let makeTwitchRequestForStreamersFollowers = (streamer_id) => {
var urlForPagination = `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows? 
to_id=${streamer_id}&first=5&after=`
var totalFollowers = 10
var keepTrack = 0


request({
url: `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows? 
to_id=${streamer_id}&first=5`,
json: true,
headers: {
    'Client-ID': 'hidden'
}
}, (error, response, body)=>{
    console.log(body)
    //totalFollowers += body.total
    keepTrack += body.data.length
    value = body.pagination.cursor
    console.log('--------------------------------')
    console.log('--------------------------------')
    console.log('--------------------------------')
    console.log("totalfollowers variable is at " + totalFollowers)
    console.log("Keeptrack variable is at " + keepTrack)
    console.log(value)

    var i = keepTrack




            paginateRequest(urlForPagination, value, (data, num)=>{
            console.log(data)
            keepTrack += data.length
            console.log(keepTrack)


        });


    });


};  


let paginateRequest = (url, pagination, callback) =>{

    request({
        url: `${url}${pagination}`,
        json: true,
        headers: {
            'Client-ID': 'hidden'
        }

        }, (error, response, body)=>{
            value = body.pagination.cursor
            callback(body.data, body.data.length)
        });





};

makeTwitchRequestForStreamersFollowers(46458435, true)
```

Comment: Can you share the [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of what you've attempted thus far?  I think it would entirely possible to load an API request into a request buffer queue and keep enqueueing requests with the cursor/pointer to the next chunk.

Comment: Yes I can Drew, 1 sec

Comment: I had a while loop there, but i realized it would fire off the first request the amount of times I had it <than. I'm still a fairly new programmer and am doing this for fun.

Comment: Are you trying to send next request after previous is done?

Answer (score 0):

I think the while loop is good, you might've been missing some conditional or not consumed the responses correctly.  Here I've tried creating an artificial api request that returns chunked data and one possible solution to working with it.

```js
// Mock Endpoint code
const arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19];

// Returns data in two element chunks
const getChunk = (index = 0) => {
  const data = arr.slice(index, index + 2);
  const nextIndex = index + data.length < arr.length ? index + data.length : null;
  return {
    data,
    nextIndex
  }
};

const apiRequest = async request => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(getChunk(request)), 250); // Simulate some latency
  });
}

// Component code
const someFunction = async (maxResults = -1) => {
  const start = Date.now();
  let requestIndex = 0;
  let canRequest = true;
  let results = [];

  while(canRequest) {
    await apiRequest(requestIndex)
    .then(response => {
      // Fold response into result and check if can make another request
      results = response.data.reduce((arr, element) => {
        if (maxResults === -1 || arr.length < maxResults) {
          arr.push(element);
        }
        return arr;
      }, results);
      requestIndex = response.nextIndex;
      canRequest = (maxResults === -1 || results.length < maxResults) && requestIndex;
    });
  }
  return {results, time: `${Date.now() - start}ms`};
}

const displayResults = results => console.log('Final results', results);

// Each call to someFuncion takes some "time" to process each wrapped api call
someFunction() // fetches all
.then(displayResults);
someFunction(0)
.then(displayResults);
someFunction(1)
.then(displayResults);
someFunction(2)
.then(displayResults);
someFunction(5)
.then(displayResults);
someFunction(10)
.then(displayResults);
someFunction(20)
.then(displayResults);
someFunction(30)
.then(displayResults);
```

Comment: That works as well. Thank you. I found a way to make the request within the request after hours of staring at my screen. I posted it as top answer.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT - Below code makes the request over and over until there is no data left for the streamer. It allows me to make requests to the server dynamically based on a streamers follower numbers.**

```
var results = 0

let paginateRequest = (streamer_id, pagination)=>{

request({
url: `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows? 
to_id=${streamer_id}&first=100&after=${pagination}`, 
json: true,
headers: {
    'Client-ID': 'hidden'
}

}, (error, response, body)=>{
    console.log(body)
    for(var i =0; i < body.data.length; i++){
        results += 1
    }


    if(body.pagination.cursor){
        paginateRequest(streamer_id, body.pagination.cursor)
        console.log('function was called for pagination')
        console.log('-----------------------------------')

    } else{
        console.log('Paginate request returned ' + results + ' followers for this user')
    }


});


};


paginateRequest(46458435, '')
```